# Sql Server update with conditional join

Tags: sql-server

I am looking for a way to combine these two statements into one in SQL server.  I tried searching for "conditional join" but didn't see this exact example  Thanks for the help.

```
update
    employees
set
    employees.RefID = ed.RefID
from
    #tmpEmployees employees 
    inner join EmployeeDirectory ed on ed.ABC = employees.ABC
where
    ( nullif(ed.ABC, '') is not null and  nullif(employees.ABC, '') is not null)



update
    employees
set
    employees.RefID = ed.RefID
from
    #tmpEmployees employees 
    inner join EmployeeDirectory ed on ed.DEF = employees.DEF
where
    ( nullif(ed.DEF, '') is not null and  nullif(employees.DEF, '') is not null)
```

Comment: After much testing, I decided on sticking with the individual update statements.  This solution seems to work the fastest.  Thank you all for your feedback.  I'll continue to monitor this post for other ideas.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I fully understand what you are trying to accomplish, but perhaps the following would help:

```
UPDATE
    employees
SET
    employees.RefID = ed.RefID
FROM
    #tmpEmployees employees 
JOIN EmployeeDirectory ed 
  ON ed.ABC = employees.ABC OR
     ed.ABC IS NULL AND employees.ABC IS NULL OR
     ed.DEF = employees.DEF OR
     ed.DEF IS NULL AND employees.DEF IS NULL
```

If the `NULL` value handling is not what you want (or the opposite of what you want), you can modify/invert it.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
UPDATE e
   SET e.RefID = d.RefID
  FROM #tmpEmployees e JOIN EmployeeDirectory d 
    ON e.ABC = d.ABC OR e.DEF = d.DEF
 WHERE NULLIF(e.ABC, '') IS NOT NULL 
   AND NULLIF(d.ABC, '') IS NOT NULL
   AND NULLIF(d.DEF, '') IS NOT NULL
   AND NULLIF(e.DEF, '') IS NOT NULL
```

or

```
UPDATE e
   SET e.RefID = COALEASCE(d1.RefID, d2.RefID)
  FROM #tmpEmployees e LEFT JOIN EmployeeDirectory d1 
    ON e.ABC = d1.ABC LEFT JOIN EmployeeDirectory d2 
    ON e.DEF = d2.DEF
```

Comment: Thanks for your input but this only matches if all of the ids (ABC and DEF) are populated.  I need it to match if either set matches.  Changes the AND conditions to OR in the where clause causes things to run much more slowly than the original post of separate update statements.